# I want to use a for loop to close some methods

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to close some repetitive statements using a for loop.

My statements are like this:

```
st1.close();
st2.close();
st3.close();
st4.close();
st5.close();
```

And I would like to use something like this to close them in a loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i<6; i++) {
st(x).close();
}
```

But I do not know how to format this. I understand that I can print to a console but I'm not sure if I can loop this type of code.

Comment: You can use an array/list and then iterate over it.

Comment: What happens when the first one throws an error? What should happen?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html)?

Comment: `List.of(st1, st2).forEach(YourClass::close);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arraylist to add all objects and iterate over it. For eg:

```
List<YourClass> myList = new ArrayList<YourClass>();

// add objects of your class to this list
myList.add(st1);
myList.add(st2); // etc..    

// iterate over the list
for (YourClass obj : myList) {
   obj.close();
}
```

Comment: This over simplifies the problem - ensuring that call things `close()` in all circumstances, and no errors are "lost" takes a bit more code...

Answer (score 0):

You can write a utility method like this:

```
public static void close(Closeable... closeables)
{
    try
    {
        for(Closeable c : closeables)
           c.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
close(st1, st2, st3, st4, st5);
```